# Where is the definition of trace_smbus_write? （linux i2c-driver）

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver, i2c

I am reading the i2c driver sources code of linux(buildroot-2018.02.5). I found a function

```
trace_smbus_write(adapter, addr, flags, read_write,command, protocol, data)
```

in i2c_smbus_xfer in i2c-core.c.

I cannot jump to its definition by ctags, so I searched with grep -R at the top directory of buildroot but no definition was found in .c or .h files.

Grep says it is included in the binary file vmlinux and vmlinux.o. The function is also shown in System.map. In this case, how can I know how the function works?

Comment: By using Google.

Comment: Did you find the definition by using google? I couldn't. If you found it, telling me the url is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see it is defined in the file include/trace/events/smbus.h (I have linux-4.18.6 kernel source) using the macro 'TRACE_EVENT_CONDITION'.

Comment: Thank you. I could find smbus.h but mine doesn't have such macro. Could you show me the macro in your smbus.h?

Comment: @john The `TRACE_EVENT_CONDITION` macro is defined in "include/linux/tracepoint.h". The "include/trace/events/smbus.h" file has only existed since the 4.13.x kernel. Between 3.15.x and 4.12.x inclusive, the SMBUS event tracing stuff was defined by "include/trace/events/i2c.h" instead of "smbus.h". Before 3.15.x, I2C/SMBUS tracing didn't exist at all.